# partial product of two matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to find a vectorised trick to calculate the products between row `i` and col `i` of two matrices, without wasting resources on the other products (row i and col j, i!=j).

```
A <- matrix(rnorm(4*5), nrow=4)
B <- matrix(rnorm(5*4), ncol=4)

diag(A %*% B)
```

Is there a name for this product, a base R function, or a reshaping strategy that avoids a `for` loop?

```
for (ii in seq.int(nrow(A)))
    print(crossprod(A[ii,], B[,ii]))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`rowSums(A * t(B))` seems to be quite fast:

```
A <- matrix(rnorm(400*500), nrow=400)
B <- matrix(rnorm(500*400), ncol=400)

bF <- function() diag(A %*% B)
jF <- function() rowSums(A * t(B))
vF <- function() mapply(crossprod, as.data.frame(t(A)), as.data.frame(B))
lF <- function() {
  vec <- numeric(nrow(A))
  for (ii in seq.int(nrow(A)))
    vec[ii] <- crossprod(A[ii,], B[,ii])
  vec
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(bF(), jF(), vF(), lF(), times = 100)   
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr        min         lq     median         uq       max neval
#  bF() 137.828993 183.320782 185.823658 200.747130 207.67997   100
#  jF()   4.434627   5.300882   5.341477   5.475393  46.96347   100
#  vF()  39.110948  51.071936  54.147338  55.127911 102.17793   100
#  lF()  14.029454  18.667055  18.931154  22.166137  65.40562   100
```

Comment: good idea! especially that I don't need to transpose, I can construct B with the correct form already

Comment: Good idea! Could you also add a comparison with an explicit for loop?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
mapply(crossprod, as.data.frame(t(A)), as.data.frame(B))
```

Comment: probably rather inefficient I'm afraid; mapply is a wrapper around a for loop, and data.frames are typically much slower to access than matrices

Comment: I know, I know. I don't see anything wrong with the for loop, btw. `[]` should have little overhead for matrixes.

Comment: it's mostly curiosity, I must confess; eventually I'm going to do this in c++, and for loops don't really matter anymore, except for legibility.